# Import to Custom Field with Tab setting

Tags: custom-fields, import

I created a custom field with a Tab setting, but when I go to Import the custom field is not visible as an option for importing.  Custom fields that are inline are visible.  Is this a limitation or a bug or something unique to my set-up?

Comment: If you can replicate the problem on a civicrm demo site https://civicrm.org/demo then you should probably go ahead and report on JIRA with the steps to replicate

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have set your Fields to be Searchable. I think that if they are not Searchable, then they also do not show on Import. There is no difference, in terms of importing, between a Group of Fields that is set to Inline v one that is set to Tab.

Comment: Yes, the fields are set to be searchable.  When I move the fields to a field group that is a tab I cannot import (the field is not listed as an option when I import) but if I move the field to a group that is inline I can import.  I have tested this problem with  more than one field and in more than one environment and it seems to be a consistent problem.  I would really like to solve it, if you have some ideas.